# C: How to use strtok to output grades from input file & find average, minimum and maximum?

Tags: c, strtok, text-parsing

I'm trying to output grades of assignments from an input file, as well as output the average, minimum and maximum grades for each assignment.

As an example, the input file for a class with 4 students and 3 assignments may look like:

```
8.5, 10.5, 90.5
49.5, 99, 97
88, 88, 100
88.5, 99, 0
```

and the output should be

```
Student grades from the input file:
8.5, 10.5, 90.5
49.5, 99.0, 97.0
88.0, 88.0, 100.0
88.5, 99.0, 0.0

Assignment # 1 stats
avg = 58.6
min = 8.5
max = 88.5

Assignment # 2 stats
avg = 74.1
min = 10.5
max = 99.0

Assignment # 3 stats
avg = 71.9
min = 0.0
max = 100.0
```

So far, I'm stuck on the first part where I have to output the contents of the file. This is what I have so far, any help on this or the functions would be much appreciated.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input_file;
    int line_number = 0;
    char *next_field;
    char line[MAX_STUDENTS+1];

    input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //OUTPUT THE GRADES FROM THE INPUT FILE
    while (1) {
        fgets(line, MAX_STUDENTS, input_file);
        if (feof(input_file))
            break;

       next_field = strtok(line, " \n");


    while (next_field != NULL) {
            printf("==================================/n");
            printf("Student grades from the input file/n");
            printf("==================================/n");
            printf("%s,", next_field);

            next_field = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char line[MAX_STUDENTS+1];` Should reconsider. string convert to double by use `strtod`.

Answer (score 0):

You could tokenize and output like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int   line_number = 0;
  FILE *input_file;
  char  line[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1];
  char *next_field;
  char *end_field;

  if (1 == argc)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (NULL == (input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
  {
    perror(argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "Student grades from the input file:\n");

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file))
  {
    int first = 1;

    ++line_number;

    for (next_field = strtok(line, ",\n"); NULL != next_field; next_field = strtok(NULL, ",\n")) 
    {
      errno = 0;

      double grade = strtod(next_field, &end_field);

      if (errno || end_field == next_field || *end_field)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: malformed input '%s'? Skipping!\n", next_field);
        continue;
      }

      fprintf(stdout, "%s%.1lf", (first ? "" : ", "), grade);
      first = 0;

      // TODO: store grade (or at least running min, max, avg) in a structure that stores assignments stats for later processing and printing
    }

    if (!first)
      fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You'll need to store stats about each assignment in some kind of structure so that you can print out the assignment stats after you are done reading in all the input.

Note that I call `strtok` with ",\n" rather than " \n" as I believe comma is really the important delimiter in your input.  At least, that's typically true for .csv files, which is a common format for delimiting data to be processed.

Note, that both of our approaches would do some worrisome things on different kinds of input.  For example, your tokenization wouldn't work well if a line looked like `"7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0\n"`, which is common in .csv files.  Your program would likely only process `7.0` and ignore the rest of the line.  Your program also likely wouldn't object to input like `"7.0,HiThere 8.0, 9.0\n"`.  Then again, your program would likely process `"7.0 8.0 9.0, 10.0\n"` the same as it would `"7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0\n"` even though some commas were missing from the former string.  Is that good or bad?  The answer depends on your input file format and how strict you want to be on its structure.  For the former string, my tokenization approach would object to the `7.0` not being followed immediately by a `','`, `'\n'` or `'\0'` in the original input, but does allow white space before a number begins, which is a somewhat strange asymmetric treatment of whitespace.  It would also blithely process `"7.0,,,,10.0\n"` without even noticing the "missing" fields on the line.

So, you need to figure out how picky you want to be and how good of error handling you want in your program.

Comment: Minor: As many think of "line length" as not including the `'\n'`, suggest using `char  line[MAX_LINE_LEN + 2];`